# Power supply for HP Workstation xw4100

Tags: power-supply, workstation

Does anyone know if the HP Workstation xw4100 takes a "special" power supply?

I know there was a time when everyone was using their own PSs with different pinouts, but I was under the impression that enough people complained and all the companies switched to standard power supplies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two options for XW4100 power supplies with part numbers:

Part No.                       Description

331223-001              Power supply assembly - 100-127VAC and 200-240VAC nominal input(switch selectable), 47-63Hz, 280 watts, .5VDC auxilary

331223-001N             Power supply assembly - 100-127VAC and 200-240VAC nominal input (switch selectable), 47-63Hz, 280 watts, .5VDC auxiliary - Mounts in the upper rear of the chassis assembly

.

HP/COMPAQ was known for having proprietary pinouts for their power supplies.

---

I Hope This Helps...

Comment: @pjemmert - it's not necessary (or indeed useful) to have a sig on all your posts, and is generally frowned upon.

Comment: I'm sorry for offending anyone.  That must be the etiquette item that I missed when reviewing the FAQ's.  Again, thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's in the FAQs ;) Don't worry about offending anyone, I only spotted it as I saw two of your answers in quick succession.